# Magento Event Observer to Change Prices

Tags: magento, events, observers, adminhtml

I looking for a Event to be triggered when a user, via adminhtml or API/SOAP, change prices of a product.

I have been check this, unsuccessfully: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

If the event you are looking for does not exist, think about doing overridden the core, at the time the product is safe. What do you think of this idea?

Any idea is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well.

Beside that i would to like to say that it is safe to over ride the product. And the Link which you have give in your question is also very much useful to you from that you will get the file which you are required to over ride.

Take the help from that and you are half way there.

Thanks and Waiting for your Comments too :) :) ;)